# Lightning vs series of resistors

Tags: electrostatics, lightning

So I was wondering if, theoretically, can a series of resistors kill off lightning current or make it low enough to sustain a battery?

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia: "Positive lightning strikes tend to be much more intense than their negative counterparts. An average bolt of negative lightning carries an electric current of 30,000 amperes (30 kA), and transfers 15 coulombs of electric charge and 500 megajoules of energy. Large bolts of negative lightning can carry up to 120 kA and 350 coulombs.[38] The average positive ground flash has roughly double the peak current of a typical negative flash, and can produce peak currents up to 400,000 amperes (400 kA) and charges of several hundreds coulombs.[39][40] Furthermore, positive ground flashes with high peak currents are commonly followed by long continuing currents, a correlation not seen in negative ground flashes."

So, considering that all available resistors have a power rating (the maximum amout of power it can hold safely), and using the expression $P=R.I^{2}$ to make an estimate of the power, you will see that, as niels nielsen said in his answers, it would be very dangerous due to the great amount of heat generated.

If you'd lika a more specific answer about the resistors specifications I suggest you also post your question at Eletrical Engineering Stack Exchange (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

probably not. the voltage levels (and transient currents) present in lightning discharges are so high that resistors of ordinary construction would explode when hit by it. And the necessary experiments would be VERY dangerous to perform!